# Does factory method pattern follow template pattern, and abstract factory pattern doesn't?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

In Design Pattern by Gamma et al, "Factory Method" has the following structure:

[image]

"Abstract Factory" has the following structure:

[image]

Why does `Creator` has a method `AnOperation()` to call`FactoryMethod()` in Factory Method pattern, while `AbstractFactory` doesn't have a method to call `CreateProductA()` and `CreateProductB()` in Abstract Factory pattern?

Does `Creator`'s method `AnOperation()` calling`FactoryMethod()` follow the Template pattern, whose structure is

[image]

?

Comment: Yes both patterns follow the Template Pattern.

Comment: Please see a previous answer of mine which directly addresses this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786084/1371329.

Answer (score 1):

A factory is a class that is dedicated to create instances of defined types. This is the ONLY purpose of a factory. A factory method on the other hand can exist on any non-factory type. The factory method diagram tries to express this by adding an arbitrary method (in UML a method is called operation) to the class to show that its main purpose is not to create instances of some other types.

You are wrong when you are interpreting the diagram like `AnOperation()` is calling `FactoryMethod()`. The diagram says `Creator` is an abstract type that has an abstract method called `FactoryMethod` and a concrete (or non-abstract) method called `AnOperation`. `ConcreteCreator` derives from `Creator` and inherits `AnOperatio()` (which is not repeated in the UML class specification since it is not abstract) and the abstract `FactoryMethod()`. `AnOperatio()` and `FactoryMethod()` are two independent methods.
´

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: given "first-order factory" servers creation purpose (basically, a bunch of `new` statements done rightly), an "abstract factorty" - or "higher order factory" - is a special case when the created object is itself.. another factory. It's kinda similar to a list of lists.

P.S. You could also have a factory that creates a factory that creates a factory. It won't be useful in most realworld cases, though perfectly fits "higher order factory" definition.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the Factory method nor the Abstract Factory pattern are applications of ("follow") the Template Method design pattern. Although the UML class diagram of their solution template may look similar, they actually help accomplish different goals.

The two factory patterns are concerned with allowing subclasses to customize how objects of a certain type are *created*. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13029261/11595728) for a discussion of the differences between the different factory patterns.

The Template Method design pattern is not concerned with the creation of objects, but rather in introducing variation points into an algorithm.

This being said, what all three patterns have in common is that they *defer some behavior to subclasses*. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55461586/11595728) for an alternative take on your question.

Answer (score 0):

*I suppose you mean Template Method pattern.*

> Does factory method pattern follow template pattern?

Yes, it does. A method which is a *factory method* is exactly a kind of a template method. The only special thing is that a factory method creates and returns an object, while a template method can do anything.

> abstract factory pattern doesn't?

No, it doesn't. The Abstract Factory pattern follows the Strategy pattern in which *aggregation/composition* is used instead of *inheritance*.

Comment: The first half of this answer is totally correct. The second half seems to imply that every use of composition is an instance of the Strategy Pattern.

Comment: No, I didnt mean that. I just mentioned composition to compare with Factory/Template Method patterns where inheritance is used. And yes, I agree that every use of composition is not necessarily Strategy pattern.

Comment: Abstract Factory uses composition; but I would not say that it follows the Strategy Pattern. Most OO patterns use composition.

Comment: Maybe the word “follow” is too strong but IMO the Strategy is the clearest example of patterns using composition.